# Drupal - Private Content Type without URL access

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i created an additional content type called "clients" where I can create new client records.
I mostly reference to this type to retrieve data.

Now I'd like to make this content type inaccessible from the outside world.

Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tonnes of ways to do it....

Check out http://www.drupalace.com/blog/2008_08_29/limiting_node_access_three_quickneasy_tools

Answer (score 1):

Review this: http://drupal.org/project/modules?text=content+access